# Adding multiple outcomes to excel IF staements

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

=IF(A15=H2,D2,"")

Can I add to the above statement or use something different to get the following outcome:

A15 = the information I have in the cells from H2:H12. When I use H2:H12 it give me an error because A15 won't equal all the information. I need to make the statement use only one out of the 10 cells. Is there a way to list it or break it up into multiple IF statements or use and OR command?

I also tried =IF(A15=H2,D2,""IF(A15=H3,D2,"")). This does not work either. A15 = H2 correctly but A15 = H3 does not show D2.

I am using Excel Office 2010

Comment: `=IF(A15=H2,D2,IF(A15=H3,D2,""))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A15,H2:H12,0)),"",D2)
```

or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H2:H12,A15)>0,D2,"")
```

Edit:

```
=IF(A15<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A15,H2:H12,0)),
            IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A15,H14:H20,0)),"",E2),D2),0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. It brings up another question though. 
When I use the IF statement your provided "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A15,H2:H12,0)),"",D2)" I receive "#VALUE!" when A15 is blank. How would I have it show "0"

Can I add to this another portion to this statement? I would like the have A15 also check H14:H20 and if it matches it would equal E2.

Comment: =IF(A15<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A15,H2:H12,0)),
            IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A15,H14:H20,0)),"",E2),D2),0)

This does not want to work. It doesn't matter what is entered into A15, it show nothing in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(OR(A15=H2,A15=H3,A15=H4,A15=H5,A15=H6,A15=H7), D2, "")
```

You can expand the OR clause to include up to H12